# Using the Facebook API to get users who have "liked" you

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

How do I use the facebook api to get the list of users who have liked my business facebook page?

I understand I can get users who have liked certain objects (ex: photos) by doing this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<obj id here>/likes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an FQL Query to `like` table.

Like this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="your_page_id"
```

See this Documentation For `like` Table ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/ )

If you want specifically for Page Likes (which are called page Fans) then `page_fan` Table can be queried.

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = your_page_id
```

See this Documentation For `page_fan` Table http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

Comment: "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 

    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException",

Answer (score 1):

This functionality isn't possible for Page objects with the Graph API or FQL, please see:
[How to list facebook users who like a page or interest](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)